# Encoding from Mac OS Roman to UTF8?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, character-encoding

I am trying to convert a [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Romana) string to a UTF8 string:

`MacRoman: OneBW/1 Schwarzwei§:`

I am using these calls:

```
nBufLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_MACCP, 0, macRomanString.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_MACCP, 0, macRomanString.c_str(), -1, tempWchar, nBufLen);
```

At this point:

`tempWhar = OneBW/1 Schwarzweiß:`

Now I am making this call:

`WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, tempWchar, -1, temp, nBufLen, NULL, NULL);`

I am expecting `temp` to be in UTF 8, but I'm getting return value `0`, which is unsuccessful translation, something string in `temp`. How do I know string in `temp` is in UTF ?

Am I doing it the right way or is something missing? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the error code returned by WideCharToMultiByte?

Comment: Is `WideCharToMultiByte()` part of some API? I don't recall any standard C/C++ function by that name...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, it's provided by Windows.

Comment: Error code is 122, I am trying to format the error message, can you suggest how to do that

Comment: Error code 122 is `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`. Your `temp` buffer is too small. PRO TIP: When something doesn't work, check the error code and then look up what the error code means.

Comment: temp = new char [nBufLen]; I am using this to assign buffer size, how do I know how much to allocate even before converting.

Comment: If I ignore the error message and printed what ever is in temp
Result: OneBW/1 SchwarzweiÃŸ: "%PlaceHodler"ýýýý««««««««þîþîþîþ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WideCharToMultiByte` will take single wide characters from the input and convert them to multiple characters in the output. Thus in most cases the output will be larger than the input. You're passing the same buffer size that you got from `MultiByteToWideChar` so naturally the buffer is too small.

You can get the required buffer size the same way you did for `MultiByteToWideChar`, passing 0 for the buffer size and using the returned value.

The reason you see garbage at the end of the string when the function fails is because the buffer didn't have room for the necessary terminating null character. Printing the string runs off the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, your output buffer is too small.  Try something like this instead:

```
int nBufLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_MACCP, 0, macRomanString.c_str(), macRomanString.length(), NULL, 0); 
if (nBufLen != 0)
{ 
    std::vector<WCHAR> tempWchar(nBufLen, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_MACCP, 0, macRomanString.c_str(), macRomanString.length(), &tempWchar[0], nBufLen); 

    nBufLen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &tempWchar[0], tempWchar.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (nBufLen != 0)
    {
        std::vector<CHAR> tempUchar(nBufLen, 0);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &tempWchar[0], tempWchar.size(), &tempUchar[0], nBufLen, NULL, NULL);

        // use tempUChar as needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i convert tempWhar to string, I need to return a string

Comment: Like this: `std::string result(&tempUchar[0], tempUchar.size());` or this: `std::string result(tempUchar.begin(), tempUchar.end());`